# On the properties of characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G=H \times K$ is a finite group such that $H_1 char H$ and $K_1 char K$, then is it true that
$(H_1 \times K_1)$ char $(H \times K)$?

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, take $G = \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ with $H_1 = 2\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $K_1 = \mathbb{Z}_4$. Let $\phi \colon G \to G$ swap the two components, i.e., $\phi(x,y) = (y,x)$. The subgroup $H_1 \times K_1$ is not preserved under $\phi$.